# Matlab: open files 'outside Matlab' by default

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm looking for a way to have Excel files in my Matlab folder open 'outside Matlab' (i.e., by MS Excel in most cases) directly by double-clicking the file, rather than right-clicking and selecting 'Open Outside Matlab'.

The .xls files reader built in Matlab can be terribly slow for large files, and an unwanted double-click on a file can cost quite some time in which Matlab is unresponsive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click something in the Current Folder tab, it's actually running the `open` command, which itself calls `finfo` to determine what it means by "open" for a given extension.  You can see this by creating a breakpoint in `open.m` directly after the line `[~, openAction] = finfo(fullpath);` and double clicking - when it hits the breakpoint you'll see it returns `openAction` as `uiimport`.

In theory, you can create custom methods for extensions by creating on the path a function `openabc` where `abc` is the extension, which should be returned as the `openAction`.

However, if I look at my `finfo.m` it first searches for said functions and then regardless of whether or not it finds them if there is an inbuilt method it overwrites them with the standard behaviour. There's even a comment:

`% this setup will not allow users to override the default EXTread behavior`

If you are willing to muck about in the inbuilts, you may be able to do it like this (backup first! - this could affect other things). I did it temporarily by shadowing the existing `finfo` like this:

`edit finfo.m` (Now save a copy to the current folder)

Add these lines after the loop that defines the `openAction` (in my version, around line 85):

```
if any(strcmp(['.' ext], matlab.io.internal.xlsreadSupportedExtensions))
    openAction = 'winopen';
end
```

From the folder containing your edited `finfo.m`, type `which finfo -all`.  You should see two copies, the MATLAB one labelled as shadowed.  Opening something from the current folder window should now open Excel externally.

Comment: It worked, but now with that `finfo.m` in my path I can't open Simulink files by double-clicking anymore. I receive an error 'in open file, line 163'. Renaming my finfo.m and therefore unshadowing the original fixes the problem. But I can't understand why, as the file I'm opening has .slx extension. Does `finfo.m` have to be located in the Matlab folder for Simulink to work?

Comment: Ah, it looks like `openslx` and similar are private functions which won't be seen when running the new `finfo`.  You could rename/backup the original and put the new version into the MATLAB directory, or copy the "private" folder, which should be found wherever the original finfo was, in its entirety to the location where the new finfo is. (I can't promise nothing else will break, though).

Comment: As I didn't have the rights to modify that folder, I copied in my project folder as in your second suggestion. It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any straightforward way to do that. It's built in to MATLAB that Excel files will open in the import tool when you double click on them, and there's no way to change that.

You might be able to get around it by changing the file extension on your Excel files to something other than `.xls` or `.xlsx`. That would stop MATLAB from opening it in the import tool. Then in Windows, you could associate the new file extension with Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your unswer. It's a smart workaround. 'xlsread' and 'xlswrite' would even still work on the new extension. However it's quite impractical, especially if these files are to be shared with other people.

Comment: @raggot Yes, I agree. The real answer is unfortunately just no, there's no way to do that.